# How to get VmList from CiscoUCS?

Tags: vmware-vcenter, hardware, blade-server, blade-chassis, cisco-ucs

We are using XML API to connect CiscoUCS Manager and get all the hardware components.

We are in the requirement of getting all the VM deployed in the bladeServer. But not able to find these information in the Cisco UCS Manager.

Can anyone help me out how to get the deployed VM List in a UCS bladeServer?.

Comment: UCS is quite new, and it sounds like you're quite early on in your deployment - this would suggest you have a current support contract with Cisco - so have you tried them first - we always try to get support from the vendor first.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't query this from your VMware vCenter?

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the information from VCenter? Which parameter would be tied up between bladeServer and VCenter VM's. @ewwhite